# How to pass jquery variables to controller salesforce

Tags: apex, javascript

Below is the javascript code . Please tell me how to pass variables a, a1  my apex controller -

Comment: There is an additional </script> in your code.

Comment: In your `actionfunction` add `rerender`. it will solve your problem.

Comment: Is it really off-topic?

Comment: I think the real question is, why not just bind the dates directly to the controller instead of this Javascript rigamarole?

Comment: I wouldn't say the question is off-topic, but not very specific. You could optimize your posted to the bare essentials, and provide us with more description of your problem and question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apex:actionFunction` and `apex:param` to pass variables to apex controller.

Please refer the link
http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/passing-parameter-in-actionfunction-in-visualforce/

Comment: Hi reshma.. I hv updated my code with action:function.. I am not seeing any debug logs.. Can u check whats is wrong..

Comment: Put console.log in your vf page and check a and a1 has value. Call callcontroller(a,a1)  method after you get values in a and a1.

Comment: I am getting the values of a, a1. If i am calling callcontroller(a,a1) in myFunction() function after i get values of a, a1, the page is getting refreshed..

Comment: @learnjqueery - add rerender=""

Comment: Thanks Eric. So Eric if i am having 2 start and end dates. How to hold them in a array in javascript.

Comment: Hi Eric.. Actualy i am dynamically creating div tags which hold the dates. The no of div tags i create i need to create that much records. So i need to hold all the dates in a array or list by javascript